# sIFR in list-items with custom bullets problem in IE

Tags: sifr

I have a design where sIFR is needed for a vertical menu. With sIFR I replace li-items (with nested lists). In my CSS I have turned off the bullets but for some of the list-items I have made custom bullets with the well-known background-image and padding-left method. It all works well on FireFox (both PC and Mac) and Safari, but IE starts showing bullets where I don't want to, and besides that it replaces my custom bullets with normal ones. sIFR seems to break my CSS for those custom-bulleted list-items.

I have tried putting every  tag in the list inside  tags and replace them with sIFR to no avail.

It would be great if someone can take a look and help me with this problem:

[www.jeroenholthuis.nl/hd/hd-bullet-problem](http://www.jeroenholthuis.nl/hd/hd-bullet-problem)

Cheers,

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be (partially) because you are applying list-style: to the li's.  It should be applied to the ul instead, which is then inherited by the li's.  That should get rid of the unwelcome bullet points at least.

I ditched using sIFR ages ago because it was overly complicated - Cufon seems like a much better solution, provided it's not over-used (slowness).

Comment: I have added a rule to my CSS: ul { list-style: none; } Even now there are bullets appearing in IE. I really don't understand what is going on. It is like sIfr erases or replaces all styles for UL and LI.

Comment: try ul { list-style-type: none; }, it's just a random guess but there is a chance IE isn't behaving with just list-style.  I ditched using sIFR long ago in favour of Cufon also, so that may be an option if problems continue.